# Delayed LUKS encrypted drive mount with password prompt not visibly asking password

Tags: mount, encryption, fstab

I have an ubuntu MATE setup 18.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-23-generic x86_64)
I want to have an encrypted $HOME while the rest remains unencrypted. Additionally, I decided to use btrfs with zstd compression algorithm (the "why" is outside the scope of this question).

Due to how the PC will be used. There's a need to wait for internet until the decryption password is needed, at which point, the password may be asked to the user in any form.

At first, I encountered these symptoms:

If I leave the whole `/home/myUser` encrypted, I'm unable to login. After I fill the password, I'm left hanging.... Until the timeout happens and lightdm gives up logging in. If I use a different tty, I'm also left hanging except the $HOME is changed to "/"

If I change, in fstab the mount directory to somewhere inside `$HOME`, I can login normally but I'm never given the prompt to fill the password when I want to access the encrypted directory (although the directory is visible when doing ls).

After investigation, I found out that:

1. if I successfully login,
2. try to access `/home/myUser/crypt` (see below)
3. then run `systemd-tty-ask-password-agent --query` in a terminal,

there's a password waiting to be filled.

I also noticed that, if instead of running the terminal, I just stop lightdm and stay on tty7, the text "Please enter password with the systemd-tty-ask-password-agent tool!" appears.
At that point, I can't get back to lightdm in that tty. Instead, I have to use a different tty to login, fill the password and now mount has completed and all is running properly.

My objective is to have a GUI password prompt for the password at the time the directory needs to be mounted. Any program may initiate the mount but I need the user to get the prompt visibly without the need of running extra tools.

I also tried to make a `keyscript` to use with crypttab which would initiate the command prompt and prompt for password but it was failing to start. I guess because there was no keyfile.

---

Below, I'm using `noauto,x-systemd.automount` but I could also use `_netdev` and get almost the same symptoms as above.
When using `_netdev`, the only difference is that the encryption password prompt (as text) flashes on the screen right before lightdm starts Xorg.

---

/etc/fstab

```
/dev/mapper/encryptedHome   /home/myUser    btrfs    user,noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=10,compress=zstd,lazytime,relatime   0 0
```

/etc/fstab (alternate try which allows me to login):

```
/dev/mapper/encryptedHome   /home/myUser/crypt    btrfs    user,noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=10,compress=zstd,lazytime,relatime   0 0
```

/etc/crypttab

```
encryptedHome  UUID="92ab7f24-c744-4f1a-8363-c1fa157d1c12"  - luks,noauto
```

**Note:** In my linux startup flags, I removed the `splash` option; because of that, I see all tty text until Xorg is started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to reuse the password you insert when logging in and get your home encrypted, while entering your password only once, one possible solution is to use **pam_mount**
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pam_mount

First, you can install it using `apt install libpam-mount`

Then, you need to configure pam_mount what is supposed to reuse the password.
For that, create a file at `/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml` with contents as follows:

```
<volume user="user" fstype="crypt" path="/dev/disk/by-partuuid/96au7f24-gbshmec6wwabhh30" mountpoint="/dev/mapper/user_home"/>
<volume user="user" fstype="auto" path="/dev/mapper/user_home" mountpoint="/home/user"/>
```

You may be able to do all with just one volume tag but I was unable to as I needed to do a binded mount.

Do note you may need to use some options, set as attributes of the `volume` tag, such as:

```
options="bind,rw,user,exec,suid,noauto,lazytime,relatime"
```

You can learn more of what each one is in the `mount` manual pages.

Finally, create the file `/etc/pam.d/system-login` and write the following:

```
#%PAM-1.0

auth       required   pam_tally.so         onerr=succeed file=/var/log/faillog
auth       required   pam_shells.so
auth       requisite  pam_nologin.so
auth       optional   pam_mount.so
auth       include    system-auth

account    required   pam_access.so
account    required   pam_nologin.so
account    include    system-auth

password   optional   pam_mount.so
password   include    system-auth

session    optional   pam_loginuid.so
session    optional   pam_keyinit.so       force revoke
session [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_succeed_if.so  service = systemd-user quiet
session    optional   pam_mount.so
session    include    system-auth
session    optional   pam_motd.so          motd=/etc/motd
session    optional   pam_mail.so          dir=/var/spool/mail standard quiet
-session   optional   pam_systemd.so
session    required   pam_env.so
```

I don't know exactly what each of these does individually but this is what I needed to have there so the mount would succeed as I wanted.